# In the graph of Inverse Cotangent Function , Why aren't numbers represented on the X axis?

Tags: trigonometry

For example , In the Graph of Inverse Sine Function The number y = 1 and y = -1 is represented as follows

[Inverse Sine Function Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuOLq.png)

Why isn't the same case followed with the Inverse graph of cotangent ?
For reference , This is the graph of Inverse cotangent Function

[Inverse Cotangent Function Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i58uY.png)

Comment: This seems to be a simple style choice (for better or worse) by the person who made the picture. Perhaps the goal is to highlight the asymptotic nature of the graph without the distraction of specific points.